# ng-repeat in select tag not producing results

Tags: angularjs

Having a lot of trouble with ng-repeat in a select tag. The below is not working for some reason though all documentation indicates that it should.

```
<select id="blahh" ng-model="log_instances" class="selectpicker" multiple>
  <option>this works</option> <!-- this works -->
    <option ng-repeat="comp in env.status.components">test-value</option>
</select>
```

The only option that ends up showing is the 'this works' one, but I would expect 'test-value' to show up for each of the items described in the ng-repeat's.

Additionally, I also checked the console for `angular.element(document.getElementById('blahh')).scope()` and it shows the proper data that I would expect to see. Also, if I include a table right below this select with the same ng-repeat's and fields, it produces the expected output just fine. I'm using Angular 1.6.5

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) only permits `<option>` or `<optgroup>` elements as children (i.e. you're generating invalid markup). Why don't you use the [ng-option](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) attribute on the `<select>` instead?

Comment: ah yes good point @miqid but that means the above (edited) should work?

Comment: as in, i just tried the above and it still doesn't work :/

Comment: I guess my suggestion wasn't clear enough—don't use `ng-repeat` at all and instead use `ng-options`. Here's a example of how to use it, of course adapt it to your case: http://plnkr.co/edit/YZ5UzY0Tx8hxT76BCdbl?p=preview

Comment: ah yes this works, and since you were first to suggest this, i can mark your answer right if you want to provide below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML snippet included with the original question had `<span>` tags as immediate children of the `<select>` tag, which would've produced invalid markup as only `<option>` or `<optgroup>` elements are permitted.

Whenever you have a data collection that needs to be presented as a select list, Angular's [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) attribute makes it easy.

<kbd>[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/YZ5UzY0Tx8hxT76BCdbl?p=preview)</kbd>

Also, if you need a default option (for when the collection data might be in transit due to an AJAX request), include an `<option>` element assigned with an empty value (i.e. `value=""`), then you could use `ng-if` to hide this default option when it is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-options` like below. But your code also should work check `env.status.components`

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

My question to you would be, why do you want to use a `ng-repeat` inside a multiple select, when you have [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) handy?

Assuming your `comp` object looks like this:

```
{
  name: 'somevalue'
}
```

I would change your code to look like so:

```
<select id="blahh"  multiple="true" ng-model="log_instances" ng-options="comp.name for comp in env.status.components"></select>
```

Please have a look at the [plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Og5f8WWM1MGnNGKigsE9?p=preview) I have made for you